# wix - how to delete non-empty folder

Tags: c#, wix

I have read all topics on this site with problem like this, but not find what i need.

I have two versions of one program: old and new.
In old version i have folder f1.
In new version i have no this folder f1.

When installer of new programm detected old version, it delete this old version, but not folder f1.

How can i delete f1 from installer of new version?

```
      <Component Id ="deleteall"  Guid="AA11A32B-9E1E-458A-8C94-3EFEDA77E494" >
        <RemoveFolder Id='iDocDir' On='both' />
      </Component>

      <Directory Id="iDocDir" Name="iDocs">
      </Directory>
```

not working =(

Comment: Are you doing a major upgrade or a minor upgrade?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should check out the [`RemoveFolderEx` element in the UtilExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_removefolderex.htm). It does exactly what you want. [Bob Arnson has blogged about it before.](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/01/21/tactical-directory-nukes/)

```
<Component Id="deeletall" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <util:RemoveFolderEx Id="RemoveiDocDir" On="uninstall" Property="iDocDir" />
</Component>
```

It works by writing temporary rowes to the `RemoveFile` table. There are restrictions to using this, however, as noted in the manual:

> Because it might dramatically affect Windows Installer's File Costing,
>   the temporary rows must be written before the CostInitialize standard
>   action. Unfortunately, MSI  doesn't create properties for the
>   Directory hierarchy in your package until later, in  the CostFinalize
>   action.
>
> An easy workaround for a typical use case of removing a folder during
>   uninstall is to  write the directory path to the registry and to load
>   it during uninstall.
>
> If you use custom actions to set properties, ensure that they are
>   scheduled before the  WixRemoveFoldersEx custom action.

And also in Bob's post:

> As adding directories and files to be deleted affects MSI’s file
>   costing, RemoveFolderEx  has to do its thing before costing.
>   Unfortunately, MSI doesn’t set up properties for  target directories
>   until after costing is complete.

If you already save your previous installation path (Rob explains how to do this [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern)) in the registry, you're fine, as the AppSearch action runs before CostInitialize.

Comment: Warning: On="uninstall" removes also the folder on an upgrade.